# Is there a way to pay my credit card balance with bitcoins?

Tags: payment, balance, bitcoin-credit-card

So imagine that I have 200 USD on my credit card balance from a bunch of small purchases and bar drinks and tips that I want to pay using bitcoins.

I know that I can but gift cards from gyft or do online purchases using joinsnapcard. But If I invite a round on my local non-bitcoin-friendly bar, I want to pay with bitcoin anyways (even I I use credit card system as proxy)

Is there any service that does that for me?

**Edit 2017-07-27**:  There is a debit card that can be funded with Bitcoin, Ethereum and Litecoin (via Coinbase) called ShiftCard https://www.shiftpayments.com/

Thanks,
Nico

Comment: So you want someone to sell the bitcoin for you then send out a check to your card company? Why wouldn't you do it yourself? It's only a few steps.

Comment: [This](http://www.gyft.com/) might be able to handle it. There might be other similar services, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you live in the states the only service that comes close to this would be

https://www.xmlgold.eu/  - you can even order a pre-paid credit card that you are able to top up with bitcoins.

https://www.okpay.com/en/index.html - Okpay used to offer the same service but due to regulatory reasons they have ceased offering thier services to US citizens.

The only other way I can think of to do this would be to use http://bitcoin-otc.com/  here you  can see if you can find anyone willing to pay off your credit card for bitcoins.  Its kind of like online trading pit.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, xmlgold.eu service is new to me.   about "anyone willing to pay off your credit card for bitcoins,"  I should only give them my credit card number right? how would they pay?

Comment: UPDATE now https://www.xmlgold.eu/ says "Country restriction: We do not serve customers from USA, please accept our apologies."  Any idea why? any other service?

Comment: Lately it is observed that the Crypt Currency is used for malicious purposes, so countries have started banning the services to reduce similar usage in their country.

Answer (score 1):

talk has been appearing lately of PayPal considering to accept Bitcoin. That would give you a somewhat direct interchange between the "two worlds" though at rather considerable cost (PayPal commissions, their outrageous bid/ask spreads, plus fixed base-fee)...

Answer (score 0):

For Canadian credit cards, you can use the service of YesToBitcoins.com, although it supports credit cards only, so no prepaid credit cards.

Comment: This looks like a valid solution, but the site doesn't do a great job of explaining themselves (their explainer videos are worthless), and neither does your answer.  Perhaps you could edit your answer to give a better explanation about what this service does and how it solves the OP's problem.